# Update same rendering of several templates using SPE

Tags: powershell-extensions, coveo

I have a bunch of templates that have a Coveo Search Box View rendering associated with the standard values. I need to update the property "Reveal Advanced Query Suggestions" of all of them(a lot of templates in this case) and set them all to checked = false. Although I could manually update them all I'm looking for an automated way of doing such a task. Anyone have done anything similar using Sitecore PowerShell?
I do have the PowerShell documentation and if I spend some time and play with it I'll figure that script on my own just wondering if anyone has ever done anything similar that they could share?

Thanks

Comment: Is that property on the rendering parameters or on the item?

Comment: The property is a rendering parameter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quick test confirms that the following allows you to set a rendering parameter on existing items.

```
# Path to the Coveo rendering you need to update
$rendering = Get-Item "master:\sitecore\layout\Sublayouts\Sample Sublayout"

# Update this value for the path of all the templates whose std vals you wish to update
$items = Get-ChildItem -recurse master:\sitecore\templates\Sample

$items | % {
    $renderingInstance = Get-Rendering -Item $_ -Rendering $rendering
    if ($renderingInstance) {
        Set-Rendering -Item $_ -Instance $renderingInstance -Parameter @{
            # Put new/changed rendering parameter name and value here
            # Other existing values should be unchanged by this
            "Lorem" = "Ipsum"
        }
        Write-Host "Updated $($_.Paths.FullPath)"
    }
}
```

More information:

- [`Get-Rendering`](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Get-Rendering.html)
- [`Set-Rendering`](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Set-Rendering.html)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks techphoria414

Comment: As soon as I can get Gitbook to build this example will be added.